# Can't generate a uuid in Mongo schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create an id in my Mongodb 4.x schema with the following code, but I get an error saying uuid not defined.

```
_id: { type: String, default: function genUUID() {
    uuid.v1()
}}
```

This looks like I have everything right.

What can I be missing?

I guess a follow up question is, how would you auto generate an _id for a single value field in your schema.

Example:

```
var ProfileSchema = new Schema({
highschool:{
  item: { type: String },
  _id: { type: String, default: uuid.v4}
},
college:{
  item: { type: String },
  _id: { type: String, default: uuid.v4}
});


var ProfileSchemaIds = new Schema({
   highschool: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProfileSchema.Highschool' },
   college: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProfileSchema.College' }
   // ... rest of your schema props
});
```

Comment: I have a use case where I need to generate _id for individual fields within a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you really need is a reference between the 3 models where `Profile` would have a reference to `HighSchool` Schema and to `College` Schema like this:

```
var ProfileSchema = new Schema({
   highschool: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Highschool' },
   college: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'College' }
   // ... rest of your schema props
});
```

`Highschool` and `College` would be separate schemas etc.

More information on [`mongoose populate etc`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-ref)

Comment: So I don't have to make I don't have to make an object within an object? How do I add that to the example I have above, where I create the myfield name and and ID for it? Thanks!

Comment: I added how I'm doing it now in my example in the original post.

Comment: I am using mongoose.

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it. So if you look at my updated example, I would create another schema that points to the fields in my original schema and by using the 'ref' I will essentially be appending the _id?

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with mongoose better and its schema relationships via `ref`. You would only have one ProfileSchema and `mongoose` would be able to fill those documents (College/Highschool) with the `populate` method. Your example is not correct. Look at this link: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html  and the example with the `story` schema etc

Comment: I see. Thanks, Akrion!